# Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: t.txt (No such file or directory)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I wrote a `scala script` named `updateTables.scala` and created a `.txt` file named `t.txt`under the directory `com/sk/data` in IntelliJ IDEA. One clause in `updateTables.scala` tries to read `t.txt`:`val wholeQuery = Source.fromFile("t.txt")`.

I use `mvn clean package` in Windows PowerShell to obtain a `jar` package from the project `SparkScalaExample` and then use `spark-submit` to execute the jar package. But error `FileNotFoundException` is thrown out.

I have tried various paths of `t.txt`, such as
absolute path `D:\SparkScalaExample\src\main\scala\com\sk\data\t.txt`,
path from content root `src/main/scala/com/sk/data/t.txt`,
path from source root `com/sk/data/t.txt`, but none of them works. Put `t.txt` under `SparkScalaExample` doesn't work either.

The following picture is the directory structure of project `SparkScalaExample`.

[image: directory structure]

So, where should I put `t.txt` and which path of `t.txt` should I use?

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: `val wholeQuery = Source.fromFile("t.txt")` is actually `val wholeQuery = scala.io.Source.fromFile("t.txt")`

Answer (score 1):

Because I run spark-submit on a server, If I want to read file `t.txt` by `Source.fromFile`, two requirements have to be met:

1. `t.txt` has to be in the server;
2. the path of `t.txt` in `Source.fromFile` has to be where it is located.

After meeting the two requirements, it works!